# What does "change my time for the reservation" mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean "change my time to suit the reservation" or "change my reservation (time)"?

"I'd like you to change my time for the reservation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a typical context: The person is calling a restaurant about their booking, it would mean "I want to change the reservation time".

When you book a table at a restaurant you normally book it at a certain time and this time can possibly be changed.

I don't know what "change my time to suit the reservation" means, but I think you should say "Change my schedule to suit the reservation" instead. Of course, you wouldn't need to tell the restaurant that.

However, instead of "my time for the reservation" I would use "The time of my reservation" or simply "My reservation time"

Comment: *change my time for the reservation* is very idiomatic AmE, where hodgepodge is the special of the day.